# Set Default Value Of WCF DataMember Property

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to add a new property bool IsValid to my class below. I want this property to be NOT Required and set to false by default. I am using this object for wcf purposes, how do I set the default value to false?

```
[DataContract]
    public class OrderLineItem : IExtensibleDataObject
    {
        ExtensionDataObject IExtensibleDataObject.ExtensionData { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Guid LineItemID { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public string ProductID { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you want it to be required (i.e., it must be present in the wire), it doesn't matter what the default value is, it will be overwritten by what comes on the wire.

Comment: Im sorry its NOT Required, let me change that

Comment: by default it will be false

[DataMember]
public bool IsValid {get; set;}

Comment: @HatSoft, you're right, `false` being the default value for `bool` didn't occur to me (my bad). The answer I have is for the general case, where you want to set an arbitrary value. If you post your comment as an answer you'll definitely have my upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by default it will be false, so nothing else needs to be done.

```
[DataMember] 
public bool IsValid { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 13):

**Update**: I answered it thinking about how to define a default value for any arbitrary type, but, as @HatSoft mentioned in the comment, you don't need to do anything to set `false` as the default value of a `bool` property, since it's already the default value for that type. I'll leave this answer for the general case, though.

There's no way to set the default value on the [DataMember] attribute itself, but you can use an [OnDeserializing] callback to set it. This way, if it doesn't come from the wire, it will have the value set by the code which ran before the deserialization.

```
[DataContract]
public class OrderLineItem : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    ExtensionDataObject IExtensibleDataObject.ExtensionData { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid LineItemID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string ProductID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }

    [OnDeserializing]
    void BeforeDeserialization(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        this.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing the below:

```
    private string _recordId;

    [DataMember]
    public String RecordId
    {
        get { return _recordId ?? (_recordId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()); }
        set { _recordId = value; }
    }
```

here "_recordId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString());" sets default value to Guid when the object is